# svg image zoom , pan and edit

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have an svg image. I want to zoom when the mouse scroll and I want to drag the image. I am able to drag and zoom it when it is an image. But I want the svg image to be in the object for further editing.

```
<div id="pcontainer1" class="pancontainer">  <img src="abc.svg" id="abc_svg" data="abc.svg"  width="900"  type="image/svg+xml" height="900"/>  </div>
```

I used these following scripts:
 - jquery.kinetic.min.js
 - jquery.mousewheel.min.js
 - imagepanner.js

To zoom the abc.svg. It is working fine. But If i place it as an object like this:

```
<div id="pcontainer1" class="pancontainer"> <object id="abc_svg" data="Corp_BluePrint_FACT_Accounting_updated.svg"  width="900" height="900" type="image/svg+xml"> </object></div>
```

the zoom and pan is not working when i place it as an object as above

Answer (score 1):

[svg-pan-zoom](https://github.com/ariutta/svg-pan-zoom) seems to be a good option for you. It is a simple pan/zoom solution for SVGs in HTML. I have worked with this lib with a number of projects, and it just works like a charm.

Check out this simple <s>[demo <sup>404</sup>](http://ariutta.github.io/svg-pan-zoom/demo/inline.html)</s> and find out more on their GitHub page.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.. But here in demo widows.load is used. I have Many functions in my code SO i can't use windows.load. Is there any alternative?

Comment: I want to call the svg image in this object to zoom and pan
<div id="pcontainer1" class="pancontainer"> <object id="abc_svg" data="abc.svg"  width="900" height="900" type="image/svg+xml"> </object></div>